# juju (canonical-kubernetes bundle) Master support HA?

Tags: juju

I am trying to use juju (canonical-kubernetes bundle) to setup kubernetes. It works well with simple master.

Is there steps to make the master HA? I just change the unit# in the bundle and re-deploy it but seems both master stop at following stage.

-------Waiting for kube-system pods to start----------

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: there is related post as http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-setup-kubernetes-master-ha-on-centos/

just wonderring if there is existing steps to follow.

Or I have to manually stop the master controller and add KUBE_SCHEDULER_ARGS="--leader-elect"?

Comment: Got the answer from https://github.com/juju-solutions/bundle-canonical-kubernetes/issues/366

"Note that if you already have a canonical-kubernetes deployed, you can add another master with: juju add-unit kubernetes-master."